# Set range of values for turtles

Tags: netlogo

I need to set a range of values for a turtle, the range must go from >= 3 to <= 5 .

I wrote this code

`if ((a) + (b) + (c)  >= 3  <= 5) [set pcolor gray]`

But I did not get what I expected

Comment: if (a + b + c >= 3 and a + b + c <= 5) [set pcolor gray]

Answer (score 3):

```
let value a + b + c
if 3 <= value and value <= 5 [ set pcolor gray ]
```

Edit:

So I put in the `let value a + b + c` to simplify the code, but that might be confusing. Here's the version that most closely matches what you have in your question:

```
if ((3 <= a + b + c) and (a + b + c <= 5)) [ set pcolor gray ]
```

That said, I recommend using a local variable as I did above so you don't have to write out `a + b + c` multiple times.

Comment: I did not explain myself. I already have this code   
If (pcolor = blue ) and ( a + b + c + d >= 3 ”*” <= 5) [set color black]
* I suppose there is something missing here

Comment: try with " and a + b + c " instead of *.. i'm not sure if i get the problem since  i already gave you this answer and it looks fine. Also Bryan Head's one is perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Like you said the code that works looks like this 

if ( pcolor =  red) and (a + b + c  <= 5 and a + b + c  >= 3) [set color orange].